# How to get the user input from the Spinner - Javafx

Tags: javafx, input, spinner, fxml, factory

I created a Spinner with JavaFx accepting Integer only. The user choose a number between 0 and 10 (number of turns he decides to rest ingame). 
However, I want to get this value when the user clicks on the "OK" button.
Here is the line where I want to call the user input. (I tried .getValue() but it's not working) :

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    RestOK.setOnAction(e -> ToF.rest((int) RestSpinner.getValue(), restTime));
}
```

And this is the fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.cc.view.RestController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="66.0" layoutY="46.0" text="How many turns do you need for resting?" />
      <Separator layoutX="81.0" layoutY="83.0" prefWidth="240.0" />
      <Spinner fx:id="RestSpinner" editable="true" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="109.0">
      <valueFactory>
          <SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory max="10" min="0" />
      </valueFactory>
      </Spinner>
      <Button fx:id="RestCancel" cancelButton="true" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeRest" text="Cancel" />
      <Button fx:id="RestOK" layoutX="276.0" layoutY="109.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="OK" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Thank you

Comment: Post code as text (code blocks) in the question, not as images. Furthermore ***what exactly*** does not work? Is there a compile time error? Is an exception thrown at runtime? Does the button simply not do anything at all? Have you replaced the call to your method with printing the spinner value to the console to make sure the issue is not the method you invoke?

Comment: 1 turn = 3 seconds. So if the user types 3 turns, he has to wait 9 seconds to go back to the game. I printed "1 turn" each time a turn happens, but it doesn't stop, it is infinite. The code doesn't take into account the value the user typed. It keeps writing '1 turn' for 3 seconds, but never stops.

Comment: The logic described is certainly not part of the code you provided. The code you posted seems to work (? according to your description ?) but the error seems to be in some part of the code you didn't provide any info about (the `rest` method of the type of `ToF`). This makes the question unanswerable in it's current state.